# Java - average value for select range of numbers inputted

Tags: java, average, mean

need a push in the right direction.
I'm supposed to make a program that calculates the average value of numbers under 100, over 100, and states the number of inputs in both categories along with the numbers of inputs being exactly 100.   oh yeah, and it's due in a few hours..  all suggestions and ideas are much appreciated'

```
import java.util.*;

public class miun
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String Tick = "";  
  int sum = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  double mean = 0.0;
  Scanner NumScanner = new Scanner(System.in);


  System.out.print("Enter number: ");
  Tick = NumScanner.next();
  System.out.println();

  while(!Tick.contains("-")) {
       sum += Integer.parseInt(Tick);
       counter++;

       System.out.print("Enter number: ");
       Tick = NumScanner.next();
       System.out.println();

  }

  mean = (sum*1.0)/counter;

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("The average value of the numbers is: " +mean);
  System.out.println("You entered a total of " +counter +" numbers");


}
}
```

Comment: This is a bad question. You're not asking anything specific and you've basically asked us to do your assignment for you. Having said that, if all you want is a push in the right direction. I'd start by having separate counters and totals for the numbers under 100 and the numbers over 100 and the instances of 100.

Comment: "it's due in a few hours" You should have started earlier.

Comment: Also, just as a side note, variable names should all start with lower case. So "numScanner" instead of "NumScanner" or else it looks like you're using a static method in a Class

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, create two counters and two sums, one set for the small numbers and one for the large ones.  Then calculate the two averages.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) and [Mean](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html) or [Median](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Median.html) classes. Here are [usage examples](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html)